# Display a child page and its children only

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am working on a theme and I am stuck on the menu. The website has several child pages and those pages have children. What I want to achieve is when you click on a child page, it displays a menu with the child page and its children only.

Home
About
Events
-**Event 1**
-**Event 2**
--Venue
--Food
--Music
-**Event 3**
Contact

What I want is when I click on Event 2, It displays Event 2 and its children only and not Event 2s siblings.

My current solution displays all the child pages i.e. Event 1, Event 3. Please find my code below.

```
<?php
// find parent of current page
if ($post->post_parent) {
   $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
   $parent = $ancestors[count($ancestors) - 1];
} else {
   $parent = $post->ID;
}

$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&depth=2&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0");

if ($children) { ?>

  <ul class="list-children">
      <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to fetch the parent. If you want to get the children of "Event 2", then it will be the parent - you don't want to fetch its parent first. You also want to set the `depth` to 1 to just return 1 level.

```
// assuming that $post == "Event 2"
$args = array(
    'child_of'    => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    'depth'       => 1,
    'title_li'    => ''
    'echo'        => false
)
$children = wp_list_pages( $args );
```